# missing partial modifier on declaration type Error

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, expression-blend

I'm new to the expression blend. While developing a desktop application I got an error saying "missing partial modifier on declaration type", but I have corrected it by putting `partial` keyword in between public and class. After correcting it I got the errors below, I would be thankful to you if you would be kind enough to give proper solution to these errors

```
The name 'startPoint' does not exist in the current context  
C:\Documents and Settings\acer\Desktop\my inter\rrrr\dragDrop(test1)\dragDrop(test1)\Window1.xaml.cs    24  9   dragDrop(test1)
```

```
The type or namespace name 'contact' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
C:\Documents and Settings\acer\Desktop\my inter\rrrr\dragDrop(test1)\dragDrop(test1)\Window1.xaml.cs    67  32  dragDrop(test1)
```

```
The type or namespace name 'Contact' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
C:\Documents and Settings\acer\Desktop\my inter\rrrr\dragDrop(test1)\dragDrop(test1)\Window1.xaml.cs    67  13  dragDrop(test1)
```

Code:

```
private void List_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    startPoint = e.GetPosition(null);
}

private void List_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    Vector diff = startPoint - mousePos;
    Contact contact = (contact)listView.ItemContainerGenerator.IndexFromContainer(listViewItem);
    DataObject dragData = new DataObject("myFormat", contact);
}

private void DropList_Drop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    listView.Items.Add(contact);
}
```

Comment: Please post the relevant code from the file "Window1.xaml.cs". Post code around lines 24 and 67.

Comment: private void List_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e){                                   startPoint = e.GetPosition(null);}                                                             private void List_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e){       
Vector diff = startPoint - mousePos;
Contact contact =(contact)listView.ItemContainerGenerator.IndexFromContainer(listViewItem);
DataObject dragData = new DataObject("myFormat", contact);{
private void DropList_Drop(object sender, DragEventArgs e){  
listView.Items.Add(contact);}}}

Answer (score 0):

To solve the first error, add this class member: (just declare it on top outside any method)

<strike>Point startPoint = Point.Empty;</strike>

```
Point startPoint = new Point();
```

The second error is more tricky.. from what I've seen, `IndexFromContainer` method returns integer, but assuming `listViewItem` is already of type `Contact`, try changing the line to:

```
Contact contact = (Contact)listViewItem;
```

Looks like you're missing the definition for `Contact` class.. couldn't find anything standard but I guess you mean this class?

```
public class Contact
{
    public Contact()
    {
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public string Email
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public string PhoneNumber
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

Comment: Second error still exist. The first error was corrected by changing the line as Point startPoint =Point();

Comment: Thank you so much for the answers.I just want to write a program allowing the user to drag and drop an image present in one Grid view to another grid view. Even though i did the above modifications still the error is there.

Comment: Sorry, I'm out of ideas. Sounds like you're not using Expression Blend correctly, try taking some working examples and start from there.

Comment: Answer provided is correct.thanks a lot.Is it possible to write a program allowing user to drag & drop an image to an appropriate place when number of pictures are given.eg:when developing an e-learning tool to learn oop,in order to demonstrate "inheritance" i have designed an activity using expression blend.A pictorial hierarchy will be provided with some blanks.Like family tree with some blanks.Appropriate pictures will be given.I want to write a program allowing the user to drag & drop the correct picture to the correct place.can you just provide me an sample demo code or tute.thank you

Comment: Ruwani, this better be asked as new question.